# Tomcat server running but not loading in browser

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have installed TomCat8 server. Changed the default port to 65535 and now trying to access it through browser after starting tomcat server. But after entering http://localhost:65535, its saying "site can not be reached". Below are the logs of Tomcat

**

```
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.272 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.9
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.278 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Server built:          Dec 5 2016 20:18:12 UTC
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.279 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Server number:         8.5.9.0
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.279 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.280 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log OS Version:            6.1
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.280 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Architecture:          amd64
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.280 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.281 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_111-b14
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.283 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.284 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Tomcat 8.5
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.284 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Tomcat 8.5
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.286 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=d:\Tomcat 8.5
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.286 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=d:\Tomcat 8.5
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.286 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=d:\Tomcat 8.5\temp
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.287 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.Cl
assLoaderLogManager
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.287 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=d:\Tomcat 8.5\
conf\logging.properties
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.288 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: exit
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.289 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.290 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.291 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListen
er.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optima
l performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
 D:\Tomcat 8.5\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Pro
gramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32
\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Finger
print Manager Pro\;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_05\bin;C:\Pr
ogram Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program F
iles\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
5.7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;.
10-Jan-2017 20:20:35.637 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Ini
tializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-65535"]
10-Jan-2017 20:20:37.733 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.
getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
10-Jan-2017 20:20:37.738 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Ini
tializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
10-Jan-2017 20:20:37.742 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.
getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
10-Jan-2017 20:20:37.743 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load I
nitialization processed in 3649 ms
10-Jan-2017 20:20:37.817 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.st
artInternal Starting service Catalina
10-Jan-2017 20:20:37.818 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.sta
rtInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.9
10-Jan-2017 20:20:37.844 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\Tomcat 8.5\w
ebapps\docs
10-Jan-2017 20:20:38.335 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Tomcat 8
.5\webapps\docs has finished in 490 ms
10-Jan-2017 20:20:38.336 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\Tomcat 8.5\w
ebapps\manager
10-Jan-2017 20:20:38.404 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Tomcat 8
.5\webapps\manager has finished in 69 ms
10-Jan-2017 20:20:38.411 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\Tomcat 8.5\w
ebapps\ROOT
10-Jan-2017 20:20:38.451 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Tomcat 8
.5\webapps\ROOT has finished in 40 ms
10-Jan-2017 20:20:38.455 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
arting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-65535]
10-Jan-2017 20:20:38.465 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
arting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
10-Jan-2017 20:20:38.471 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start
Server startup in 725 ms
```

**

Comment: From the log, you are on a Windows machine, have you checked your firewall settings to allow port 65535?

Comment: Yes, it is WINDOWS machine. Can you suggest me steps to verify firewall issue

Comment: Did you try to access Tomcat on default port 8080 before changes you made? Did it work at http://localhost:8080/ URL? There is no problem with Tomcat if your changes are the same as in [this manual](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you definitely deployed your war file?
From the logs

```
/docs
/manager
/ROOT
```

are the only deployed web apps and iirc those come with the default tomcat installations.

Normally you also have to specify which webapp you want to access as well e.g. 
    http://localhost:65535/docs

Comment: By Default tomcat wont return anything try telneting to that port, if you have a blank terminal after the telnet then the port is opened and tomcat is listening. You need to add your project into the webapps directory of tomcat before anything will happen

Comment: @daark, You're wrong about the Tomcat default behavior. You can access http://localhost:8080 once the Tomcat has been started up with default configuration.